# 「上のごとく」対「上述」：現在では「〜のごとく」は使わないほうがいいですか。

Tags: academic-japanese, written-language

## Japanese

## 前書き

２ヶ月前、私は国内会議で発表しました。そのときは、まだ日本語のミスがたくさんある原稿を使っていました。今、文学の博士課程の友人に修正してもらっています。もちろん、これは勉強になります。修正された部分は、たいてい（私の言おうとしている意味に）的確だとわかりますし、なぜそう修正されるのかわかるのですが、ときどき私の使った表現が古かったせいなのだろうかと思うことがあり、確認したいです。

## 質問本文

私の質問は「〜のごとく」に関してです。
原稿には私は以下の文を書いていました：

> 上のごとく、道徳的自己は神の支配を愛する。

ですが、友人は修正して以下のように変えました：

> 上述のように、道徳的自己は神の支配を愛する。

別の研究で、西田幾多郎の論文を読んでいたときに、「上のごとく」（実際は「右の如く」）という表現を知って、使いました。これは古びた表現ですか。または、使い方の間違いですか。

## English

## Preface

Two months ago, I presented at an academic conference inside of Japan. At the time, I used a manuscript which still contained many errors in the Japanese. Now, I'm getting revisions from a friend who is in a humanities PhD program. Of course, I'm learning a lot from these. And I generally think the corrections are accurate (to the meaning I want to say) and can understand why the corrections work. Periodically though, I wonder if the problem is I used a outdated expression and I want to confirm that [here].

## Question itself

My question then is in relation to the use of the expression　"X no ごとく". In my manuscript, I had the following sentence:

> 上のごとく、道徳的自己は神の支配を愛する。

Approximately,  "As written above, the moral self loves to serve God."

My friend corrected it to:

> 上述のように、道徳的自己は神の支配を愛する。

(same translation).

In a different research project, I was reading an article by Nishida Kitaro, and that's where I picked up the 「上のごとく」(Actually,「右の如く」). Is this phrase outdated? Or did I use it incorrectly?

Comment: "上記の通り"も使うことがあります。[Google検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q="上記の通り"&oq="上記の通り"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.9881j0j4&client=tablet-android-asus-rev&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: 学術論文にそれが大丈夫ですか。

Comment: It’s okay. 大丈夫です。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「上のごとく」

文法的に間違っているわけではないのですが、おっしゃる通り、古い感じがするから修正されたのだと思います。As stated above を言うのでしたら、

> 「上述のように」
>   「上に述べたように」
>   「上のように」
>   または、
>   「上述のとおり」
>   「上に述べたとおり」

などがよいかと思います。

Comment: 上述のとおりです！！ wwww

Answer (score 0):

既述の

前述の通り

前述の方法に加えて

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13142200988
>   上記と前述の違いって何ですか？
>
> dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/126430/meaning/m0u/
>   ぜんじゅつ【前述】とは。意味や解説、類語。［名］(スル)前に述べたこと。既述。先述。「―のとおり」「―したように」⇔後述。

前章でも述べたが

前章で述べたように

前節で触れたとおり

前節でもかるく触れたとおり、

本章の冒頭で述べたとおり

---

re:   「上のごとく」

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/80504/meaning/m0u/
>
> ............. 「彼の言うごとく市場はまもなく安定した」「脱兎のごとく逃げ帰った」「一〇年前のことが今さらのごとく思い出される」
>   [補説]現代では文章語的表現、または改まった表現をする場合に用いられる。

The use / meaning of 「のごとく」 has shifted or narrowed.  In the last 30 years or so, 
this 1st listed usage
 「彼の言うごとく市場はまもなく安定した」 has become rare.